# Vertically centralize if content fits, scroll otherwise

Tags: android, ios, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Here is what my layout looks like:

```
<template>
<GridLayout rows="auto,*,auto">
  <GridLayout row="0" id="topBar" columns="*,*,*">
    <!-- my top bar -->
  </GridLayout>

  <GridLayout rows="*,auto,*" height="100%">
    <StackLayout row="0" />
    <ScrollView row="1" orientation="vertical">
      <StackLayout>
        <slot />
      </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <StackLayout row="2" />
  </GridLayout>

  <StackLayout row="2">
    <!-- my navigation bar -->
  </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
</template>
```

I want my `top bar` and `navigation bar` to take as much height as they need so they can fit their content properly. I want the main content which is a `scrollview` to take the rest of the height of the page.

Now depending on the screen size, my content either fully fits in the page in which case I want it to be vertically centralized within it's container which is the scrollview taking all the space between the top bar and navigation bar. So in this case there will be some empty space above and below the content, within the scrollview.

or, the content doesn't fully fit within the boundaries of the scrollview in which case The empty space above or below my content within the scrollview should disappear and the content should be scrollable naturally.

This works if the content fits, otherwise it doesn't scroll I think because it sets the height of the scrollview large enough to contain its content so it doesn't overflow anymore. How can I fix this?

Comment: You should use scroll view only above the container you want to be scrollable, that's being said it's not recommended to use it above GridLayout with partitions.

Comment: @Manoj so I would move the scrollview around the middle stacklayout? where can I find these best practices such as the one you said?

Comment: It's the more you understand how the layouts work, a ScrollView makes anything within scrollable, using GridLayout with partitions helps to split the available space so using them together may not be a good choice.

Comment: @Manoj but having a scrollview as a child of a gridlayout is fine right?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine. ScrollView itself takes allocated space and content inside will be scrollable.

Comment: @Manoj that didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set max-height in nativescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58371204/how-to-set-max-height-in-nativescript)