# How to set max-height in nativescript?

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, native, nativescript-vue

Here is my layout (It's a nativescript-vue app):

```
<template>
  <GridLayout rows="*,auto,*" height="100%">
    <StackLayout row="0" />
    <ScrollView row="1" orientation="vertical">
      <StackLayout>
        <slot />
      </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <StackLayout row="2" />
  </GridLayout>
</template>
```

Now depending on the screen size, my content either fully fits in the page in which case I want it to be vertically centralized within its container which is the ScrollView taking all the space between the top bar and navigation bar. So, in this case, there will be some empty space above and below the content, within the ScrollView.

or, the content doesn't fully fit within the boundaries of the ScrollView in which case The empty space above or below my content within the ScrollView should disappear and the content should be scrollable naturally.

This works if the content fits, otherwise, it doesn't scroll I think because it sets the height of the ScrollView large enough to contain its content so it doesn't overflow anymore.

What I think can solve this issue is that I set a max-height to the ScrollView so it's height won't be larger than the height of the screen.

Comment: Can you show a screen of what you see vs what you expect? Without seeing what you have in header and footer, it's hard to suggest the layout.

Comment: The header and footer are empty. I have put the stack-layouts as placeholders. as for the slot. you can really imagine sometimes it's just a very long text, and sometime a very short text. if it's short it should appear in the middle of the screen fully. otherwise it should take all the space in the screen and also be scrollable. I believe this question is very important and also many people were looking for such a thing in the issues of the nativescript repo. It would be really great if you can find a way to provide an answer to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
<template>
  <GridLayout rows="auto,*,auto">
    <StackLayout row="0" />
    <ScrollView row="1" verticalAlignment="center">
       <StackLayout>
         <slot />
       </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <StackLayout row="2" />
  </GridLayout>
</template>
```

I tested with Playground, it seems to give me the expected results.

[image: Center Content]

[image: Scrollable Content]